# wsdl from java code

Tags: wsdl

can somebody please tell me how to generate wsdl from java code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach would be to think ["contract first"](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/1.5/reference/html/tutorial.html): start by defining your request and response XML and generating WSDL from that.  Your Java classes are decoupled from the WSDL, and "duck typing" is possible.

This is the approach taken by Spring web services.